# How to get the list of products and prices meeting different criteria in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a pricing table as follows,

**Pricing Table**

```
id  productId  ContractId   ageGroup  ageFrom    ageTo  sellingPrice  specialPrice
1       1          1           1          0        2         0            0
2       1          1           1          3       13        20            0
3       1          1           2         18       55        80            0
4       1          1           3         56      119        60            0
5       1          1           1          0        2         0            0
6       1          2           2         18       55        85            0
7       2          2           3         55      119        90            0
8       2          2           2         18       55        90            0
```

I need to find the list of Contract Ids and Ids for given age Group (1-adult or 2-child or 3-senior). For the children the age range (from - to) need to be considered as well.

The following query (1 adult, 2 children with the ages 2 & 4 and 1 senior) seems to be working but returns only the ids matching the age group 1.

```
SELECT contractId,id 
FROM tbl_contract_price cp1 
WHERE contractId IN 
(SELECT contractId FROM tbl_contract_price cp2 
WHERE contractId IN 
(SELECT contractId FROM tbl_contract_price cp3 
WHERE cp1.ageGroup = 1 AND (cp2.ageGroup = 2 AND cp2.ageFrom <= 2 AND 2 <= cp2.ageTo OR cp2.ageGroup = 2 AND cp2.ageFrom <= 4 AND 4 <= cp2.ageTo ) AND cp3.ageGroup = 3))
```

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: What are your input (selection criteria) and expected output? You mentioned validation date, but how would I know which dates are within your rage (so I assume date is part of the input, along with product id?)

Comment: Can you mention desired output?

Comment: @TheLyrist sorry about that guys. Just edited the main post with more info. Please see if that is good enough. Thank you.

Comment: @GarimaGupta sorry about that guys. Just edited the main post with more info. Please see if that is good enough. Thank you.

Comment: How to link the 3 tables together? There doesn't seem to be a common key so that I can tell which price is valid from what date to what date. The pricing table doesn't have the valid date FK, etc.

Comment: The pricing table has the product Id and the Valid dates table has the pricing Id. Aren't we supposed to initially look for the available(valid) dates and get the pricing Ids then the product Ids that meet our search inputs in pricing table? Am I still missing anything?

Comment: @TheLyrist does that help?

Comment: The data schema makes sense now. So, confirming the logic 1. For a given date and product, retrieve all valid price options by looking at the ValidDates and Pricng tables. 2. From all the valid options, pick the contractId with the lowest adult price, which is ageGroup = 2 (Do you have logic to enforce that each pricing option will have a value for the ageGroup = 2?) 3. Retrieve the complete pricing info (for all age group) from the contract. MySQL will probably not create the multi dimensional array for you, and I think price calculation is probably best handled by your businss logic layer.

Comment: @TheLyrist I have scaled down my problem here. I just need to get the list of contract Ids and Ids from the pricing table. Do you see anything I am missing?

Comment: It seems that you are trying to pass an non-predefined number of parameters to your query, and I think that is why you are struggling. (i.e., your next query could be 5 adults, with 6 children with age of 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 7, 12). You could do that with dynamic query, but it will be super ugly and highly inefficient. you might want to restructure your question so that you don't have to handle the complex calculation in your data layer.

Comment: It seems like you want to look at all your suppliers (contract id) and return the lowest available price based on the number of adults and ages of accompanying children given a product id and a date. If there is any flexibility in the data structure, I could make some recommendations too.

Answer (score 1):

Based on some assumptions, I have created the following to help you get started. Please note that you will need to enforce your data integrity (i.e., ensuring that for each product, all possible ages are covered by a price, etc.)

I suggest that you use a temporary quote table so that you can have more flexibility on the number of inputs. You can see the data example below. Or, better yet, handle that logic within your Business Logic Layer.

You will need to apply any tie-breaker logic if two contracts yield the same price, etc.

```
CREATE TABLE Pricing (
  ID int not null,
  productId int not null,
  ContractId int not null,
  ageGroup int not null,
  ageFrom int not null,
  ageTo int not null,
  sellingPrice int not null,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

INSERT INTO Pricing (ID, productId, ContractId, ageGroup, ageFrom, ageTo, sellingPrice) Values (1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0);
INSERT INTO Pricing (id, productId, ContractId, ageGroup, ageFrom, ageTo, sellingPrice) Values (2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 13, 20);
INSERT INTO Pricing (id, productId, ContractId, ageGroup, ageFrom, ageTo, sellingPrice) Values (3, 1, 1, 2, 18, 55, 80);
INSERT INTO Pricing (id, productId, ContractId, ageGroup, ageFrom, ageTo, sellingPrice) Values (4, 1, 1, 3, 56, 119, 60);
INSERT INTO Pricing (id, productId, ContractId, ageGroup, ageFrom, ageTo, sellingPrice) Values (5, 1, 2, 1, 3, 13, 0);
INSERT INTO Pricing (id, productId, ContractId, ageGroup, ageFrom, ageTo, sellingPrice) Values (6, 1, 2, 2, 18, 55, 85);
INSERT INTO Pricing (id, productId, ContractId, ageGroup, ageFrom, ageTo, sellingPrice) Values (7, 2, 2, 3, 55, 119, 90);
INSERT INTO Pricing (id, productId, ContractId, ageGroup, ageFrom, ageTo, sellingPrice) Values (8, 2, 2, 2, 18, 55, 90);

CREATE TABLE ValidDates (
  ID int not null,
  priceId int not null,
  fromDate date not null,
  toDate date not null,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
 );

 INSERT INTO ValidDates (id, priceId, fromDate, toDate) VALUES  (1, 1, '2018-06-01', '2018-06-30');
 INSERT INTO ValidDates (id, priceId, fromDate, toDate) VALUES  (2, 2, '2018-06-01', '2018-06-30');
 INSERT INTO ValidDates (id, priceId, fromDate, toDate) VALUES  (3, 2, '2018-07-01', '2018-07-31');
 INSERT INTO ValidDates (id, priceId, fromDate, toDate) VALUES  (4, 3, '2018-06-01', '2018-06-30');
 INSERT INTO ValidDates (id, priceId, fromDate, toDate) VALUES  (5, 3, '2018-07-01', '2018-07-31');
 INSERT INTO ValidDates (id, priceId, fromDate, toDate) VALUES  (6, 4, '2018-06-01', '2018-06-30');
 INSERT INTO ValidDates (id, priceId, fromDate, toDate) VALUES  (7, 5, '2018-06-01', '2018-06-30');
 INSERT INTO ValidDates (id, priceId, fromDate, toDate) VALUES  (8, 5, '2018-07-01', '2018-07-31');
 INSERT INTO ValidDates (id, priceId, fromDate, toDate) VALUES  (9, 6, '2018-06-01', '2018-06-30');
 INSERT INTO ValidDates (id, priceId, fromDate, toDate) VALUES  (10, 6, '2018-07-01', '2018-07-31');

 CREATE TABLE Products (
   ID int not null,
   PRIMARY KEY (ID)
 );

CREATE TABLE Quotes (
  ID int not null,
  age int
);

INSERT INTO Quotes (Id, age) VALUES (1, 70);
INSERT INTO Quotes (Id, age) VALUES (1, 25);
INSERT INTO Quotes (Id, age) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO Quotes (Id, age) VALUES (1, 4);
```

Then, you can use the following query to calculate your total price based on the product id, selected date, and your quote id (which has all the ages for the particular quote)

---

Scenario: tour date = Jun 22, 2018; product = 1, quote = 1 with age = 1, 4, 25, 70

```
SELECT @tourdate := '2018-06-22', @productid := 1, @quoteid := 1;
```

First query to show how the relevant information is retrieved

```
SELECT productid, contractId, ageGroup, ageFrom, ageTo,
SUM(CASE WHEN age BETWEEN ageFrom AND ageTo THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PAXCount, sellingPrice
FROM ValidDates
LEFT JOIN Pricing
  ON priceId = Pricing.ID
    LEFT JOIN Products
      ON productId = Products.ID
        LEFT JOIN Quotes
          ON Quotes.ID = @quoteid
WHERE (@tourdate BETWEEN fromDate AND toDate) AND productid = @productid
GROUP BY productid, contractid, ageGroup, ageFrom, ageTo, sellingPrice;
```

---

second query is built upon the first query, aggregating the total so that you have the total cost for ranking

```
SELECT contractId, SUM(sellingPrice * PAXCount) FROM (
SELECT productid, contractId, ageGroup,
SUM(CASE WHEN age BETWEEN ageFrom AND ageTo THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PAXCount, sellingPrice
FROM ValidDates
LEFT JOIN Pricing
  ON priceId = Pricing.ID
    LEFT JOIN Products
      ON productId = Products.ID
        LEFT JOIN Quotes
          ON Quotes.ID = @quoteid
WHERE (@tourdate BETWEEN fromDate AND toDate) AND productid = @productid
GROUP BY productid, contractid, ageGroup, sellingPrice) P
GROUP BY contractid
ORDER BY SUM(sellingPrice * PAXCount)
#LIMIT 1;
```

1. You can uncomment the #Limit 1 to get only the cheapest package, but you need to be aware of the limitation
2. You will need to ensure that your data integrity is enforced, i.e., for each product and date range, all possible age needs to be covered by
3. Note that because the child aged 0 and the senior aged 70 were not covered by contract id 2, the $85 total is misleading. You can add logic to check if a contract can fulfil all ages (if input count is 4, check if the contract does indeed include four people, etc.)
4. You might need to clean up the quotes tables as required. It is not the most efficient approach for sure (but it should work according to your requirements).

For example, change the query to something like this:

```
SELECT @PAXCount := COUNT(*) FROM Quotes WHERE id = @quoteid;
```

Or you can probably pass that in from your application fairly easily.
Then, check to make sure that the count matches.

```
SELECT contractId, SUM(sellingPrice * PAXCount) AS TotalPrice, SUM(PAXCount) AS TotalPAXCOUNT
FROM (
  SELECT productid, contractId, ageGroup,
  SUM(CASE WHEN age BETWEEN ageFrom AND ageTo THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PAXCount, sellingPrice
  FROM ValidDates
  LEFT JOIN Pricing
    ON priceId = Pricing.ID
      LEFT JOIN Products
        ON productId = Products.ID
          LEFT JOIN Quotes
            ON Quotes.ID = @quoteid
  WHERE (@tourdate BETWEEN fromDate AND toDate) AND productid = @productid 
  GROUP BY productid, contractid, ageGroup, sellingPrice) P
GROUP BY contractid
HAVING @PAXCount = SUM(PAXCount)
ORDER BY SUM(sellingPrice * PAXCount)
#LIMIT 1;
```

This way, only contract id covering all passengers will be shown.

---

[Try it in the DB Fiddler](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gZho9aphwdae5NA63LUCYW/1#&togetherjs=yAPnEOIDIN)

Comment: Thank you. Client has come up with minor changes and working on them. This I believe will help me a lot.

Comment: I also wonder if having a temporary table as such will affect the DB performance when there are many concurrent queries?

Comment: I agree with your concerns. That wasn’t a temporary table but rather a transactional table, but that is a hack needed to get around the data structure and your requirements. That’s why you should probably look into updating your data schema, use proper caching, and let the business layer does the calculation for you. Pull the relevant pricing info, cache as required, and calculate the price, in your application.